# Where does Node.js get it's timezone and how can I set it globally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, object, timezone

I am running Windows 10 Professional and my timezone and region settings are set to Brisbane/Australia (UTC+ 10:00). Furthermore, I am running Node.js on my system for an application I am building.

I ran the following in Node.js:

```
  var x = new Date();
  console.log(x);
```

It returned the following:

> 2017-09-07T23:42:33.719Z

Notice the Z at the end of the datetime string?
This represents Zulu time. (UTC + 0)

I presume that this is set by default in Node.js when no timezone is specified. How can I specify the timezone globally in Node.js so as to ensure that all date objects a returned correctly?

Comment: No, `Z` represents UTC ~ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC. You are seeing this because the console is representing your date as a string via `Date.prototype.toISOString()`. Try `console.log(x.toString())` or `console.log(x.toLocaleString())`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean you were wrong about "Zulu" time. Hope it didn't come across like that

Comment: Isn't Zulu time just another name for UTC (And both are represented by `Z`)?

Comment: There are several questions in here.  Are you asking how to show the local time zone? Or how to set node to use a *different* time zone?  Or do you just want to know how Node is working internally?

Comment: @MattJohnson Yes.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the TZ env to a timezone string.

For example:

```
$ export TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
$ node

> Date()
'Fri Sep 08 2017 03:02:57 GMT+0200 (CEST)'


$ export TZ=America/Anchorage
$ node

> Date()
'Thu Sep 07 2017 17:04:46 GMT-0800 (AKDT)'
```

You can also set `process.env.TZ` at runtime:

```
> process.env.TZ = 'Antarctica/Mawson'

> Date()
'Thu Sep 07 2017 17:11:00 GMT-0800 (+05)'
```

Note, regardless of the timezone, `new Date()` returns UTC `2017-09-08T01:05:58.103Z` when called like this.

Comment: This only works on *nix/OSX systems.  It does not work on Windows.  The OP said they were running on Windows 10.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the clarification @MattJohnson

Comment: I changed the TZ as you said, but I have 2 problems. 1: the timezone in node is changed, but in pm2 my apps are working like before (with UTC). 2: when I restart my CentOs, the TZ is reset to UTC :(