# Moment.js uses a different time zone than the one defined in the system

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm running Moment on a laptop with Windows 10 in EST, timezone UTC-05:00. I *didn't* define the daylight savings time in the laptop, but when I run the code below Moment converts the date to UTC-04:00. Why does Moment use a different timezone than the one defined in the laptop?

```
        var ts = "2019-04-01T18:22:57.813";
        var dateTime = moment(ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').toDate();
        console.log(dateTime);
```

Comment: moment.js knows nothing about your laptop, all it knows is the javascript engine it runs in. If you need it to run in a _specific_ timezone, remember to explicitly call the locale function on it.

Comment: but the javascript engine runs with the timezone defined in the laptop, isn't it?

Comment: if you're asking me, then you're not sure, and you should _definitely_ explicitly tell moment.js which timezone to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... Windows 10 in EST, timezone UTC-05:00. I didn't define the daylight savings time in the laptop...

From your explanation, I assume your time zone settings look like this:

[image: time zone settings screenshot]

The `(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)` display name matches the Windows time zone ID of `Eastern Standard Time`, which corresponds to the IANA time zone ID of `America/New_York`.  That time zone currently uses UTC-5 during standard time and UTC-4 during daylight time.  It doesn't matter that it says "(UTC-05:00)" in the display name string, it still honors DST as applicable in that time zone.

The "Adjust for daylight saving time automatically" feature is normally turned on for time zones that have daylight saving time.  Turning it off, as shown here, is generally not recommended.  The problem is that some software will not evaluate that flag, and simply look at the time zone identifier.  For web browsers, you'll find that Edge will honor this flag, but Chrome will not.

There's really no good reason to disable this.  If you need a time zone that is UTC-5 without DST, such as `(UTC-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito, Rio Branco`, then simply choose that time zone.

And lastly, recognize that this has nothing to do with Moment.js.  You will see the same behavior just with the JavaScript `Date` object.  Since DST is in effect in US Eastern Time on April 1st, then you will see UTC-4 for that date.

On the other hand, if what you really wanted was to interpret the given date and time as being in UTC-5 *regardless* of the local computer settings, Moment can help you with that:

```
var m = moment.parseZone("2019-04-01T18:22:57.813-05:00");
m.format() //=> "2019-04-01T18:22:57-05:00"
```

Though if you do `m.toDate()`, then you'll get back a `Date` object, which is once again going to pick up the computer's local time zone.  For this scenario, try to avoid `Date` objects if you can.

Comment: We have national phone carriers. If your phone is set to pick up time and timezone information from the network because you travel and it's really handy that everything uses local time when you get off a plane, in Queensland, Australia you will incorrectly get daylight savings because the server is in another state. At this point the ability to turn it off manually is vital. I realise you are talking about computers, not phones, but these days the distinction is blurring.

Comment: @PeterWone - The case you mentioned is generally handled well already without such a "disable DST" setting.  Windows has a distinct time zone settings for `(UTC+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney` and `(UTC+10:00) Brisbanse`.  The former does DST, the latter does not.  Windows 10 also has a "Set Time Zone Automatically" setting, which will use the best location information is available on the OS.  In the case of phones, there's location but also [NITZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NITZ), which transmits whether DST is applicable or not.

Comment: That requires you explicitly set Brisbane time. Doing so involves choosing from an awkwardly long combo box list. It also sabotages picking up time-zone from the network. Toggling DST on and off is much less fiddly. If you'd like to go teach Telstra how to use NITZ you'd make me a happy camper.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks for the explanation. I run this on Chrome; changing to ON the `Adjust for daylight saving time automatically` made this code work (there's no shift to the input date).

Comment: Yep, I would recommend to most people to turn on all the automatic settings on that page.  Some might need to turn off "set time zone automatically", but only if Windows has a problem identifying the time zone for the location.  The other two should always be on.

Answer (score 0):

By default moment.js use local time zone (node timezone): https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment-timezone/01-using-timezones/05-default-timezone/
And if unset, by default node.js use UTC timezone, check out: 
[Where does Node.js get it's timezone and how can I set it globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107050/where-does-node-js-get-its-timezone-and-how-can-i-set-it-globally)